# Access azure app service with ip address not the hostname

Tags: azure, networking, azure-web-app-service

I've got a app plan (BASIC SMALL) with a private (hopefully) ip adress that can be found under Settings > Custom Domains. 
When I try to access the content of the app using just the ip, it doesn't work. The site says "Error 404 - Web app not found." The hostname works just fine. When I ping the hostname it gives me the same ip adress. What do I have to do in order to be able to access it just using the ip?

Answer (score 3):

That's not how Web Apps work, since you don't get a unique IP address assigned. You'll need to access it via `yourname.azurewebsites.net` or `yourcustomdomainname.com` - and then your requests are routed appropriately based on the name you provide.

If you absolutely needed a dedicated IP address, you'd need to deploy to a virtual machine.

Comment: yeah but it says that i can buy an external domain and forward it to this ip address. Which kinda gives the impression i have a dedicated ip? am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When you host your web site on Azure web app it is bound to **a virtual IP address that is shared with other web sites** in the same app service plan. If you want to get a dedicated IP with your web site, please try to use [Azure virtual machine with reserved IP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/reserved-ip-addresses/). You could also choose [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro)

Answer (score 1):

If you buy your custom domain, you can freely set DNS A records for that IP (it remains static). It sets binding of your domain to your web app. You can't access it directly by IP. Because on a given IP address and standard HTTP port 80, only one web can be running.

Imagine your web app could be open by entering that IP. You would "block" port 80 for zillions of other stuff running there.

If you check Properties blade there you will see a number of outbound IP addresses. If you consume some requests from web app / job / ... and have IP restriction set on the other side - you need to allow all these IPs.

As David suggested. If you really need a static IP - you need to run VM and set IP address as static or set VNet for web app.

Comment: ok!. Thanks a lot. I've created VNE under the app. It created these two services :VNE + VNE-gateway + VNE-ip. I can't change IP from dynamic to static. It says it's because the association with the gateway. I also don't know how to make that ip a "gateway" to my app. Is there any easy tutorial on how to achieve what I need? I couldn't find one.

Comment: First of all it's not possible for BASIC tier (which you probably have according to your question), you need to have STANDARD at least. You can find info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: I upgraded to STANDARD. But I still don't know how to associate that public ip ("VNE-IP service") to my app. Any ideas?